# Selector of pattern match being exhaustive

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Looking at the [Scala doc for sealed classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/123), it says:

> If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a sealed class, the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a possibility of a `MatchError` being raised at run-time.

I don't quite understand what they meant in this paragraph. My understanding is that if a switch case, doesn't cover all the possibilities, then we'll get a warning at compile time, saying we might get an error at run time. Is this correct?

I find it strange, because how can we cover ALL the scenarios in a switch case? We would have to match all possible strings, which is just silly, so I take it my understanding is incorrect. Someone care to elucidate, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I find it strange, because how can we cover ALL the scenarios in a switch case? We would have to match all possible strings

Yes, if the selector has type `String` (except it isn't a `sealed` class, because that's a Scala concept and `String` is a Java class).

> which is just silly

No. For strings, you just need a catch-all case, e.g.

```
val x: String = ...
x match {
  case "a" => ...
  case "b" => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

is an exhaustive match: whatever `x` is, it matches one of the cases. More usefully, you can have:

```
val x: Option[A] = ...
x match {
  case Some(y) => ...
  case None => ...
}
```

and the compiler will be aware the match is exhaustive even without a catch-all case.

Answer (score 4):

What the paragraph is saying is that in-case you have a fixed hierarchy structure like this:

```
sealed trait Foo
class Bar extends Foo
class Baz extends Foo
class Zab extends Foo
```

Then when you pattern match on it, the compiler can infer if you've attempted to match on all possible types extending the sealed trait, in this example:

```
def f(foo: Foo) = foo match {
     | case _: Bar => println("bar")
     | case _: Baz => println("baz")
     | }

<console>:13: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Zab()
       def f(foo: Foo) = foo match {
                         ^
f: (foo: Foo)Unit
```

Note the beginning of the [document](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/123) says:

> A sealed class may not be directly inherited, except if the inheriting
>   template is defined in the same source file as the inherited class.

This is unique to Scala, and can't be done in Java. A `final` class in Java cannot be inherited even if declared inside the same file. This is why this logic won't work for `String` in Scala, which is an alias for `java.lang.String`. The compiler warning may only be emitted for Scala types that match the above criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard character allows us to cover all the scenarios.

```
something match {
  case one => ...
  case two => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

It is selected whenever all other cases don't match; that is, it is the default case. Further information [here](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-match-expression-like-switch-statement).